# How to disable CSS errors for HTML files using Visual Studio Code (on Mac)

Tags: css, angularjs, macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio Code (on a Mac) to write AngularJS style HTML. When I insert an inline expression for a CSS value, I get the annoying red Intellisense error, as shown in the screenshot below. Also, please note that I have disabled all extensions to ensure that none were the cause of my issue.

The main question is this: how do I disable the CSS errors in VSCode for Mac?

[image: CSS Error in VSCode]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: One suggestion, dont use `{{}}` in `style` attribure, it'll create bugs at any point of time. There might be some scenarios where your `{{myCol}}` will take sometime to render and at that time your style wont be applied. Use `ng-style` , similarly check for `ng-href`

Comment: Ah, I wasn't yet familiar with the `ng-style` directive. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

open your settings.json file by cmd+shift+p OR crl+shift+p and typing setting.json

in that file add this line

```
"html.validate.styles": false
```

Comment: This worked, but I only want it to work for .liquid files. Is there a way to set it so it works in all files except .liquid?

Answer (score 2):

VSCode is still very new to me, but after some tinkering I found an option that disables all CSS validation rules. I set the value to ***false*** and the errors are now longer showing up. The setting in your *settings.json* file should appear as as follows:

```
    {
        "folders": [
            {
                "path": "/Users/Paulie/Desktop/AngularPractice"
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "css.validate": false
        }
    }
```